# Rxjs loop through nested object

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, rxjs5

RxJS how to get specific attribute values from nested array of objects

```
const obj = {
      name: 'campus',
      buildings: [
        {
          name: 'building',
          floors: [
            {
              name: 'floor'
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    };
```

Is there a way to get names in RxJS. Basically I need output as [campus, building, floor]

```
Observable.of(obj).map((res) => res.name).subscribe((val) => console.log(val));
```

I know how to do this without using RxJS. But I would like to know how to do using RxJS.
Thanks in advance

Currently I'm doing something like below

```
const names = [];
    names.push(obj.name);
    obj.buildings.forEach((building) => {
      names.push(building.name);
      building.floors.forEach((floor) => {
        names.push(floor.name);
      });
    });
    console.log(names);
```

Comment: so your goal is to check every object for a 'name' property and get them all in an array? can you post how you would do this without rxjs?

Comment: @bryan60 I updated my question with the current way. Please take a look.

Comment: What is the benefit of "doing this with RxJS"? RxJS is more intended for async work than sync work and it looks to me like this is very much sync—did you want to make it async?

Comment: @Whymarrh I was wondering is there a way to do this in RxJS and yes I would like to make it async if useful.

Comment: You might be interested in [IxJS](https://github.com/ReactiveX/IxJS) as a way to write this that would support async sources. That said, I don't think doing this in RxJS is useful as there's nothing here that would be different. If you want to "convert" the result of this operation into an Observable for use elsewhere, you can use [`Observable.from(names)`](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html#static-method-from) at the end.

Comment: Overall the reactive documentation is NOT useful for getting up to speed quickly in a pragmatic environment. Questions like these are valuable in learning reactive programming in terms of implementation. Secondly, if reactive programming isn't the best solution, the boundaries should be drawn between that and imperative programming - the documents (and any books) imply that it is a two sided coin in every example I've seen. @PratapA.K is addressing what I think is a major obstacle. With reactive, there's always a thousand ways to do it, but seemingly only 1-3 methods end up being scalable.

Answer (score 2):

this should work:

```
getNames(obj) {
    const names = [];
    names.push(obj.name);
    obj.buildings.forEach((building) => {
      names.push(building.name);
      building.floors.forEach((floor) => {
        names.push(floor.name);
      });
    });
    return names;
}

Observable.of(obj).map((res) => this.getNames(res)).subscribe((val) => console.log(val));
```

You're changing one value into another, simplest like this. There isn't a special reactive way of acting on a single value.  Reactive methods are for acting on streams of values over time, as it stands, you're operating on a single value in a stream, so best to treat it like one instead of jumping through hoops to try and do things "in the reactive way".  If you were trying to collect the "name" properties from a series of objects over time, then that would be a different story, you could use reduce or scan in that case.